# Gnosis-Chain_ID error

Tags: blockchain, gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I am trying to deploy a Safe smart contract but am getting an error that says [image: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "getChainId")]

Here is the deployment code:

```js
const { SafeFactory, ethAdapter } = require ('@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk')
import  Safe from "@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk"
import  {SafeAccountConfig} from "@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk"

const main = async () => {

    const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter })

    const owners = ['0x8Bf88c0b8865Da300a9C393860e08F2a86fbC27d', '0xEfdc4Fb960fDD5cc2110aa9a75F9ACae245b5d95']
    const threshold = 2
    const safeAccountConfig: SafeAccountConfig  = { owners, threshold }
    
    const safeSdk: Safe = await safeFactory.deploySafe(safeAccountConfig)

    
    
    console.log(safeSdk);
    
}
main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const { ethAdapter } = require('@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk')
```

is not a valid import. You should use

```js
import EthersAdapter from '@gnosis.pm/safe-ethers-lib'
```

For more information see https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-core-sdk#1-set-up-the-sdk-using-ethers-or-web3